# MySQL to pgSQL migration

Tags: mysql, postgresql, web-services, migration

We have a fairly large **MySQL** database with more than a million rows of data with every possible data type.

It is a part of a custom MVC application built more than 5 years ago. We have to migrate it now.

There are a large number of queries and insert statements which we want to replace with **JSON based web services** so that it can be used with every kind of app/device etc.

A large number of PHP functions have been fused with display logic making it tricky. Also there are also a few MySQL functions in the bundle.

Please share tips/suggestions/tools that would be useful for this migration.

Comment: Tip: google your problem and do some research before asking. Also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools which I can suggest you to convert your Mysql database to Pgsql one here is some of them:

- pgloader
- PostgreSQL Data Wizard
- pgloader
- dataPro

And based on my experience, I suggest you pgloader to load data from MySQL, SQLite, MS SQL Server, dBase files, CSV files and fixed-width data files, and more. Released under The PostgreSQL Licence..

Comment: The main worry is about re-using server side code that has tons of business logic embedded. Looking for a tool that can separate display from server side logic